# Intersection of queries using junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, junction-table

I googled but could not find a suitable response.

I have two tables -

```
Students
(
   studentid int,
   studentname text
);

Classroom 
(

  classroomid int

);
```

I created a junction table that looks like-

```
Junction
(

  studentid int,
  classroomid int
);
```

In the junction table, the combination of both values is a primary key. I want to find out which students attend classes 1 AND 2 i.e. they have an entry in the table junction which says classroomid = 1 and classroomid = 2 for the same studentid.

I tried looking up on the internet, but could not find a way to accomplish this.

I am not looking for a direct answer. Any pointers in the right direction would also be sufficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude you need to learn [Mysql Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). You can also find [Graphical Representation](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) of Joins.

```
SELECT std.studentid, std.studentname FROM Students std INNER JOIN Junction jnc WHERE jnc.classroomid IN(1,2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I did not look up the correct terminology. Thanks for the link also. I'll upvote you, once I have enough reputation to do so.